# How To Assign A Range to a String in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with dates in a table called Transactions in Excel. I have a column called transactions and I would like to iterate through the descriptions and assign them to a string. My test code is as below and I am getting a error 1004.

```
For i = 1 To Range("Transactions").Rows.Count
    ' Set group to the value returned from the DEscription Table
    strGroup = Range("Transactions[Description]")(i)
Next i
```

I need help i tried adding .Value at the end and it did not help anything

I want to basically search every cell in a particular column for specific words and if they match. Copy the text to a new column. So that's why I want to get every description as a string and then use it as a parameter in the InStr function

Comment: you can't have a range assigned to a string. You can assign a value from a range to a string.

Comment: I tried using the range.Value but that didnt help either

Comment: A `String` is one value. A `Range` is one object representing one or more cells in a worksheet; `Range` has a `Value` property, but if the range is for more than one cell then it gets you an *array of values*, which you can't legally assign to a `String`. By the way, iterating cells the way you're doing here, is the single slowest way to go about it. And even if the assignment was legal, you're overwriting it with every new iteration.

Comment: Ok I actually want to overwrite the value every time. But then I tried using the list object way but I wasn't getting what I wanted. What do you suggest

Comment: You definitely **don't** want to overwrite the value every time; otherwise when the loop exits, `strGroup` will only ever contain whatever the last iteration assigned it to, which defeats the entire point of looping in the first place (just read the last value if what you want is the last value). I'd love to help, but I've no idea what you're asking / trying to do.

Comment: I get the current cell value and check if it contains a word and if it does add that word to a column at the same index as the strGroup. Maybe I should edit my question

Comment: I've edited my question and I think it's explains better now

Answer (score 2):

maybe `join(application.transpose(range("a1:a100").value)," ")` not sure how it will perform at various sizes, but 100 rows was ok.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Comment: What happened/were you expecting?

Comment: I want to basically search every cell in a particular column for specific words and if they match. Copy the text to a new column. So that's why I want to get every description as a string and then use it as a parameter in the InStr function

Comment: You should add that bit to your question.